# Random Error 503 Service Unavailable on Varnish; its log shows no fetcherror

Tags: linux, centos, varnish

Randomly our production site encounters a 503 error; each time after a  varnish service restart, the requested site comes up normally.

I looked at the varnish log and all I see is "Service Unavailable" but nothing else.

I'm posting a portion of the varnishlog, the default.vcl and the varnish.params

> - << BeReq    >> 857875
> - Begin          bereq 857874 fetch
> - Timestamp      Start: 1553896092.649343 0.000000 0.000000
> - BereqMethod    GET
> - BereqURL       /huf_en_us/search/ajax/suggest/?_=1553896063503&q=pot+leaf+sock
> - BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
> - BereqHeader    X-Real-IP: 172.16.204.112
> - BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
> - BereqHeader    SSL-OFFLOADED: https
> - BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
> - BereqHeader    Host: www.hufworldwide.com
> - BereqHeader    CF-IPCountry: US
> - BereqHeader    CF-RAY: 4bf50bf2cb163852-LAX
> - BereqHeader    CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}
> - BereqHeader    accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
> - BereqHeader    x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
> - BereqHeader    accept-language: en-us
> - BereqHeader    listrak-listening: 1
> - BereqHeader    referer: https://www.hufworldwide.com/huf_en_us/triple-triangle-pullover-hoodie-pf00100?color=tropical-green
> - BereqHeader    dnt: 1
> - BereqHeader    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
> - BereqHeader    x-newrelic-id: VQcDV1JVABAEUVJVDgkOXw==
> - BereqHeader    cookie: store=huf_en_us; _vuid=5759a66b-8175-43cc-a614-51a32c0d7a08; PHPSESSID=los3vfdipo3ako096qoo830m05; form_key=QY53qr4aLFMypLqi; private_content_version=927393d221b9f95d0d23c147b7a38d6b; section_data_ids=%7B%22directory-data%22%3A1553894394%2C%22cus
> - BereqHeader    CF-Connecting-IP: 2606:a000:1216:8689:a5a4:dde1:69bd:10ac
> - BereqHeader    CF-Pseudo-IPv4: 252.241.164.167
> - BereqHeader    True-Client-IP: 2606:a000:1216:8689:a5a4:dde1:69bd:10ac
> - BereqHeader    CDN-Loop: cloudflare
> - BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 172.16.204.112, 127.0.0.1
> - BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
> - BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
> - BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 857875
> - VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
> - VCL_return     fetch
> - BackendOpen    54 web02(172.16.204.102,,80) 172.16.204.104 60836
> - Backend        54 d web02(172.16.204.102,,80)
> - Timestamp      Bereq: 1553896092.649819 0.000476 0.000476
> - Timestamp      Beresp: 1553896093.563128 0.913785 0.913309
> - BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
> - BerespStatus   503
> - BerespReason   Service Unavailable
> - BerespHeader   Date: Fri, 29 Mar 2019 21:48:12 GMT
> - BerespHeader   Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/7.0.30
> - BerespHeader   X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.30
> - BerespHeader   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> - BerespHeader   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
> - BerespHeader   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
> - BerespHeader   Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
> - BerespHeader   Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
> - BerespHeader   Pragma: no-cache
> - BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=los3vfdipo3ako096qoo830m05; expires=Sun, 28-Apr-2019 21:48:13 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/; domain=www.hufworldwide.com; secure; HttpOnly
> - BerespHeader   X-NewRelic-App-Data: PxQGUFJVDAUIR1VXBAYOXl0IFB9AMQYAZBBZDEtZV0ZaClc9HiBQFg1ZWT1JJUpcXhAiDVlFRQkIXVNBPkkuA1cHVhZXZGh0QQRUBEYOQQk4anYRFj9kdUILDxZ0XlkSFl5aXwcUPz55DEwHSltRQkcKS0MdUR1SVAYHUUpTFgoAXVRQGxwGSkYCAwZbUltQB1oMWw0MBQVWRxUHUA1ABzk=
> - BerespHeader   Connection: close
> - BerespHeader   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> - BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> - TTL            RFC -1 -1 -1 1553896094 1553896094 1553896092 375007920 0
> - VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
> - TTL            VCL 0 10 0 1553896094
> - VCL_return     deliver
> - BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
> - Storage        malloc Transient
> - ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
> - ObjStatus      503
> - ObjReason      Service Unavailable
> - ObjHeader      Date: Fri, 29 Mar 2019 21:48:12 GMT
> - ObjHeader      Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/7.0.30
> - ObjHeader      X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.30
> - ObjHeader      X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> - ObjHeader      X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
> - ObjHeader      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
> - ObjHeader      Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
> - ObjHeader      Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
> - ObjHeader      Pragma: no-cache
> - ObjHeader      Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=los3vfdipo3ako096qoo830m05; expires=Sun, 28-Apr-2019 21:48:13 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/; domain=www.hufworldwide.com; secure; HttpOnly
> - ObjHeader      X-NewRelic-App-Data: PxQGUFJVDAUIR1VXBAYOXl0IFB9AMQYAZBBZDEtZV0ZaClc9HiBQFg1ZWT1JJUpcXhAiDVlFRQkIXVNBPkkuA1cHVhZXZGh0QQRUBEYOQQk4anYRFj9kdUILDxZ0XlkSFl5aXwcUPz55DEwHSltRQkcKS0MdUR1SVAYHUUpTFgoAXVRQGxwGSkYCAwZbUltQB1oMWw0MBQVWRxUHUA1ABzk=
> - ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> - ObjHeader      Content-Encoding: gzip
> - Fetch_Body     2 chunked -
> - Gzip           G F E 16777 6581 80 52568 52578
> - Timestamp      BerespBody: 1553896093.572716 0.923373 0.009588
> - BackendClose   54 web02(172.16.204.102,,80)
> - Length         6581
> - BereqAcct      3058 0 3058 869 16789 17658
> - End

default.vcl

> vcl 4.0;
>
> import std; import directors;
>
> REM The minimal Varnish version is 4.0 For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer:
>   'SSL-OFFLOADED: https'
>
> backend web01 {
>       .host = "172.16.204.101";
>       .port = "80";
>       .connect_timeout = 1600s;
>       .first_byte_timeout = 1600s;
>       .between_bytes_timeout = 1600s;
>       .max_connections = 20000; }
>
> backend web02 {
>       .host = "172.16.204.102";
>       .port = "80";
>       .connect_timeout = 1600s;
>       .first_byte_timeout = 1600s;
>       .between_bytes_timeout = 1600s;
>       .max_connections = 20000; }
>
> backend web03 {
>       .host = "172.16.204.120";
>       .port = "80";
>       .connect_timeout = 1600s;
>       .first_byte_timeout = 1600s;
>       .between_bytes_timeout = 1600s;
>       .max_connections = 20000; }
>
> backend web04 {
>       .host = "172.16.204.121";
>       .port = "80";
>       .connect_timeout = 1600s;
>       .first_byte_timeout = 1600s;
>       .between_bytes_timeout = 1600s;
>       .max_connections = 20000; }

varnish.params

> REM Varnish environment configuration description. This was derived from
>   REM the old style sysconfig/defaults settings
>
> REM Set this to 1 to make systemd reload try to switch VCL without restart. RELOAD_VCL=1
>
> REM Set WARMUP_TIME to force a delay in reload-vcl between vcl.load and vcl.use
>   REM This is useful when backend probe definitions need some time before declaring
>   REM configured backends healthy, to avoid routing traffic to a non-healthy backend.
>   REM WARMUP_TIME=0
>
> REM Main configuration file. You probably want to change it. VARNISH_VCL_CONF=/etc/varnish/default.vcl
>
> REM Default address and port to bind to. Blank address means all IPv4
>   REM and IPv6 interfaces, otherwise specify a host name, an IPv4 dotted
>   REM quad, or an IPv6 address in brackets.
>   REM VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS=192.168.1.5 VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=8080
>
> REM Admin interface listen address and port VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1 VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082
>
> REM Shared secret file for admin interface VARNISH_SECRET_FILE=/etc/varnish/secret
>
> REM Backend storage specification, see Storage Types in the varnishd(5)
>   REM man page for details. VARNISH_STORAGE="malloc,24G"
>
> REM User and group for the varnishd worker processes VARNISH_USER=builder VARNISH_GROUP=builder
>
> REM Other options, see the man page varnishd(1) DAEMON_OPTS="-p thread_pool_min=200 -p thread_pool_max=2000 -p thread_pool_timeout=600
>   -p http_resp_hdr_len=90000 -p http_max_hdr=200"

Comment: 503 responses typically indicate the server is overloaded.  This issue generally is a result of heavy load rather than server issues and goes away on it's own so long as the load reduces.

Comment: which server? varnish server or web nodes?

Comment: I don't even know what a varnish server is but http responses are fairly standardized across all applications.

Comment: the reason I'm asking this is because the architecture is as follow:

Load Balancer -> Varnish Server + Nginx Reverse Proxy -> Web nodes (4) with Apache

So when you say "the server is overloaded", does it mean the web nodes are overloaded or the vanish server itself is overloaded

Comment: Monitor the performance on all your servers and find out which one(s) is/are experiencing high load at the time of a 503